# Hot Chocolate GraphQL batching Queries and applying Selection and Filtering middleware to EF SQL

Tags: sql-server, graphql, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

Using HotChocolate Version: 10.5.5

And given the following `Customer` domain model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string SalesPerson { get; set; }
}
```

When exposing the Entity Framework `Customers` dbset in a query interface:

```
[UseSelection]
[UseFiltering]
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers([Service] AdventureWorksContext ctx) => ctx.Customers;
```

And executing the following graphql query:

```
query {
  friendlyBikeShop: customers (where: { companyName: "Friendly Bike Shop"}){
    firstName,
    lastName
  },
  frontSportingGoods: customers (where: { companyName: "Front Sporting Goods"}){
    firstName,
    lastName
  }
}
```

Results in the following two SQL statements:

```
SELECT [c].[FirstName], [c].[LastName]
FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[CompanyName] = N'Front Sporting Goods'

SELECT [c].[FirstName], [c].[LastName]
FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[CompanyName] = N'Front Sporting Goods'
```

This isn't ideal as I would like to merge this into one SQL statement:

```
SELECT [c].[FirstName], [c].[LastName]
FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[CompanyName] in (N'Front Sporting Goods', N'Front Sporting Goods')
```

A first attempt to solve this problem using a `GroupDataLoader` is as follows:

```
[UseSelection]
[UseFiltering]
public Task<Customer[]> GetCustomersByCompanyName(IResolverContext resolverCtx, [Service] AdventureWorksContext ctx, string companyName) =>
    resolverCtx.GroupDataLoader<string, Customer>("customers", async keys =>
    {
        var customers = await ctx.Customers.Where(customer => keys.Any(key => key == customer.CompanyName)).ToListAsync();
        return customers.ToLookup(customer => customer.CompanyName);
    }).LoadAsync(companyName, default);
```

And executing the following graphql:

```
query {
  friendlyBikeShop: customersByCompanyName(companyName: "Friendly Bike Shop"){
    firstName,
    lastName
  },
  frontSportingGoods: customersByCompanyName(companyName: "Front Sporting Goods"){
    firstName,
    lastName
  }
}
```

Results in the following single SQL statement:

```
SELECT [c].[CustomerID], [c].[CompanyName], [c].[FirstName], [c].[LastName], [c].[SalesPerson]
FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[CompanyName] IN (N'Friendly Bike Shop', N'Front Sporting Goods')
```

The drawback to this approach is that `Filtering` and `Selection` isn't factored into the dynamically created SQL statement generated by EF, this is only applied AFTER the result set has returned from the database.

How do I return an `IQueryable` on the query interface so that the `Filtering` and `Selection` middleware will apply and be factored into the the SQL statement which is dynamically generated and still force this to be executed in a single batch?

Comment: I have the same problem which I resolved by gathering the selection context and using dynamic LINQ. However, the problem is resolved only for projecting, filtering and sorting, I still cannot figure out how to solve it for pagination. Instead of 10 items from the database it would extract all 100 items from there and then apply paging which is bad. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The data API of HotChocolate and the Dataloaders do not work well together.
These are two different approaches that cannot be mixed in the same resolver.

Filtering works on the resolver level whereas data loaders do run outside of the resolver execution.

This query contains two resolvers:

```
query {
  friendlyBikeShop: customers (where: { companyName: "Friendly Bike Shop"}){
    firstName
    lastName
  }
  frontSportingGoods: customers (where: { companyName: "Front Sporting Goods"}){
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

Therefor you can either go with filtering and projections and two queries or you go with data loaders and only execute one query.

As an alternative query you could also do this:

```
query {
  customers (
    where: { 
        companyName_in: [
            "Friendly Bike Shop",
            "Front Sporting Goods"
      ]
  }){
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

This would return both results in a single request